# Accessing contents of additional disk in Google Compute Engine

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a disk with some contents already on GCE and I'm trying to create a new VM and add that disk as an **additional disk** (not the boot disk). Is it possible to access the contents of that disk from that VM?

Comment: Usually yes. How is the disk formatted? Which file system? Is the disk in the same region? What have you tried and what are the errors? Your question is short on details.

Answer (score 0):

First, Use this command [attach-disk](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/attach-disk)

```
gcloud compute instances attach-disk example-instance \
      --disk DISK --zone us-central1-a
```

Mount this disk on Ubuntu, and make sure the disk filesystem is for Linux. Using **dmesg** to see you new attach disk

```
dmesg

[    1.380224]  sdb: sdb1
```

Comment: After attaching the instance , should we create the user's home folder in that disk?